# How to back up "The disk has S.M.A.R.T. errors" and fix the errors

Tags: mac, backup, osx-lion, disk-utility, smart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repair or recover drive from Mac OSX recovery mode](https://superuser.com/questions/486048/repair-or-recover-drive-from-mac-osx-recovery-mode)

My computer won't start up past the login screen so first i tried Safe Mode [Shift+Start up] didn't work . Then I tried to reinstall software [Command+R+Start Up] my apple logo turned into a circle with a line through it and the gear never stopped spinning [about half hour later] so I turned it off.  I then tried to reset the NVRAM [Command+Option+P+R] and I got to a screen that said "Mac OS X Utilities" from there I went to Disk Utility and saw that my disk had S.M.A.R.T. errors.  I clicked "Repair Disk" and it found the problem and fixed it apparently.  However, when I tried to reinstall Lion I got this image

[image]
So I have a few questions:

If my disk is corrupted, why did it say the repair worked ?
If my disk is corrupted, how can I back up the files if I can't login ?
Is it possible to repair the S.M.A.R.T. errors ?
I want to AT THE VERY LEAST back up my photos and a few documents, is there any way I can put those files onto a USB through Disk Utility ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You "backup" your files _before_ this happens.  You try to "recover" them _after_ the fact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repair or recover drive from Mac OSX recovery mode](http://superuser.com/questions/486048/repair-or-recover-drive-from-mac-osx-recovery-mode) also see [Recover hard disk data?](http://superuser.com/questions/87188/recover-harddrive-data) also [How to recover data from a hard drive crash?](http://superuser.com/questions/329403/how-to-recover-data-from-a-hard-drive-crash) and a few others.